# Escaping CSS / JS

Tags: zend-framework2

Perhaps I'm just not understanding the documentation just yet when it comes to Escaping JS and CSS. Currently I'm reading this section: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.escaper.escaping-javascript.html

In my current View I have the following: (Works just fine)

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/asset/login/index.js', 'text/javascript');
```

After reviewing the documentation I assume I should be doing this instead?

```
$this->escapeJs($this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/asset/login/index.js', 'text/javascript'));
```

The same would be for include CSS Files using escapeCss().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with the `appendFile` method is to make a *reference* to an external script file in your HTML markup. Although I have never used the `escapeJs` view helper, I think it is safe to say that it escapes JavaScript from a string. What you are passing to it is whatever the `appendFile` method returns (probably nothing or an object). This is pointless because there would never be anything meaningful to escape.

What you are trying to do, I guess, is to escape the *contents* of the script file that you are referencing. I do not see the purpose of doing this, and I think that you misunderstood the purpose of escaping JavaScript (and HTML for that matter). From a security perspective, you want to escape such content such that users cannot manipulate with your pages, which could impose risks to other users. What you are doing in this case is that you are trying to escape your *own* JavaScript code. This would first of all mean that your code is not parsed and executed by your browser, and besides it does not make sense because *your* own code should be trusted enough to be included on *your* pages.

You should be escaping *user supplied* data (or data that stems from a data source such as a database) to prevent Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attacks. The `escapeHtml` view helper is very convenient in this case and will handle JavaScript and CSS as well, because those would be nested inside appropriate tags to take effect.

Therefore, I think the solution to your problem is to simply not do what you are trying to do and continue doing as per your first example.

Comment: Thank you. The way you have explained this really helped me understand things more and it's exactly what I was looking for.